# There does not exist an entire function which satisfies $f({1\over n})={1\over 2^n}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

There does not exist an entire function which satisfies $f({1\over n})={1\over 2^n}$, what I tried is if possible then define $g(z)=f(z)-{1\over 2^{1\over z}}$ Then $g({1\over n})=0$ and so $g(z)$ is entire and its $0$ set has limit point in it and so $f(z)={1\over 2^{1\over z}}$ which is not analytic at $0$?
Please help!

Edit: OOps! the way I defined $g(z)$ that is not entire! could any one give me hint?

Comment: Say the first term in the Laurent series is $a_kz^k$, $a_k \ne 0$.  See what your condition does for this.

Comment: $f(z)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty} a_kz^k\Rightarrow f({1\over n})=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty} a_k({1\over n^k})={1\over 2^n}$

Comment: @Tsotsi: You are assuming that $f$ is entire and trying to find contradiction. So, just $f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k z^k$

Comment: @GEdgar: And also, Laurent series -> Power series.

Comment: @Ogastulas can you please tell from which book you this exercise

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Hint**: If $f(0) = 0$ and $f$ is not identically zero, we can find another entire function $g$ so that $f(z) = z^k g(z)$ for some positive integer $k$ and $g(0) \ne 0$.

Comment: this is clever!

Answer (score 13):

There is no  $f$, analytic in a neighborhood $U$ of $0$, with $f\bigl({1\over n}\bigr)=2^{-n}$ for all $n\geq1$, let alone an entire function with this property.

*Proof.* Such an $f$ would be not identically zero. By general principles about analytic functions there would exist an $r\geq0$ and a function $g$, analytic in $U$, with
$$f(z)=z^r \>g(z)\quad(z\in U);\qquad g(0)=:a\ne0\ .$$
It follows that
$$f\bigl({\textstyle{1\over n}}\bigr)\ 2^n={2^n\over n^r}\> g\bigl({\textstyle{1\over n}}\bigr)\to\infty\qquad(n\to\infty)\ ,$$
contradicting our basic assumption about $f$.

(Ayman Hourieh beat me by 9 minutes.)

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

$$(1)\;\;\;\;\;f\left(\frac1n\right)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$$

$$(2)\;\;\;\;\;\text{The zeros of entire functions are isolated.}$$

Comment: I don't understand how these help.

Comment: Zero is *not* an isolated zero of $\,f\,$ , thus not such *entire* function can exist.

Comment: There is no other information on zero of $f$ other than just $f(0)=0$, how do you know that 0 is not isolated zero of $f$?

Comment: Because $\,\frac1{2^n}\to 0\,$ ...!?

Comment: What do you think the Zeros of $f$ are?

Comment: I now see your point: all the time I thought $\,f(1/2^n)=0\,$ , that's the reason of my last comment. I misread. Thanks. The claim though still is true, the explanation in this case is not.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ is supposed to be entire, it is continuous at $0$.  Let $n \to \infty$. Then we must have $f(0) = 0$.  Now let $n \to -\infty$. What is $f(0)$ now?

Comment: Are you sure the OP doesn't mean $n\in\Bbb N$?

Answer (score 1):

Another proof.

Lemma. Let $w\in\mathbb{C}$. If $u(z)$ is a holomorphic function in an open subset $G\subset \mathbb{C}$ that is not a constant function $w$, then elements in $u^{-1}(w)$ are isolated.

[Proof of the Lemma]: Without loss of generality, we may assume $w=0$. Suppose $u(z_0)=0$. Let the order of $z_0$ be $m$ (must be finite, otherwise $u\equiv 0$), then $u(z)=(z-z_0)^m h(z)$, where $h(z)$ is holomorphic in $G$ and $h(z_0)\ne0$. Then there is a neighbourhood $U\subset G$ of $z_0$ such that $h(z)\ne 0$ (thus $u(z)\ne0$) in $U\backslash \{z_0\}$. So $z_0$ is an isolated point of $u^{-1}(0)$. The proof of the Lemma is complete.

Suppose there is a holomorphic function $f$ in the open unit disk such that $f(\frac{1}{n})=\frac{1}{2^n}$ for $n=2,3,\ldots$. Then $2^{n}f(\frac{1}{n})=1$ for $n=2,3,\ldots$.
Note that $g(z)=2^{\frac{1}{z}}f(z)=\exp(\frac{1}{z}\log 2) f(z)$ is holomorphic in $D\backslash \{0\}$ where $D$ is the open unit disk, and $g(\frac1n)=1,n=2,3,\ldots$.

If $g$ is constant $1$ in $D\backslash\{0\}$, then $f(z)=2^{-\frac{1}{z}}=\exp(-\frac1z \log 2)$, by any textbook about functions of complex variable, $\exp(-\frac1z)$ has a nonremovable singularity at $z=0$, so is $f(z)$. So $f$ cannot be extended to a holomorphic function in $D$, a contradiction.

If $g$ is not constant. Note that $g^{-1}(1)$ has a limit point, a contradiction with the Lemma.

The proof is complete.

Comment: Are we all supposed to know the meaning of “[Sarason, 2007]” and to have access to that textbook?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have removed the reference of Sarason's book and add a Lemma to make the proof self-contained.