# Does there exist an analytic function s.t. $f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=2^{-n}.$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Prove that there does not exist an analytic function $f$  in an unit disc containing $0$ such that $$f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=2^{-n}.$$

I tried by using Identity theorem.

Suppose that $f$ is analytic in the unit disc.

Consider the function $g(z)=f(z)-2^{-\frac{1}{z}}$.

Then the zeros of the function $g(z)$ are $\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in \mathbb N\}$ which has a limit point $0$ in the disc. So, $g$ is identically zero. Then, $f(z)=2^{-1/z}$. But, I am unable to find a point such that we arrive at a contradiction.

Please help to find it OR any other technique to prove the question.

Comment: Haven't thought carefully, but it's undefined at $z=0$... which should matter.

Comment: So, how we can proceed?

Comment: This seems related http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/392682/there-does-not-exist-an-entire-function-which-satisfies-f1-over-n-1-over-2

Comment: @S717717 can you please tell from which book can I get this question?

Comment: @user8795 Sorry..! I forget the source of this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that

$$f(z) = 2^{-1/z}$$

is not continuous at $z=0$. Indeed: For $(z_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq (0,\infty)$ such that $z_n \to 0$, we have

$$f(z_n) \to 0.$$

On the other hand, for $w_n := -z_n \to 0$,

$$f(w_n) \to \infty.$$

Since an analytic function has to be continuous, this contradicts our assumption.

Comment: Since $f(z)=e^{log(1/2)\over z}$ can we actually prove that $0$ is an essential singularity of $f$ ? The function $g(z)=e^{1\over z}$ has an essential singularity at $0$.

Comment: @SrinivasK Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @saz I do not see how this solves the problem. By the identity theorem, if both $f$ and $g$ are analytic in a domain $D$, and agree on some sequence with limit point in the interior of $D$, then $f \equiv g$. You have shown that the function $g(z) = 2^{-1/z}$ is not analytic in $D$. I do not see how this shows that $f$ cannot be analytic.

Comment: @saz The identity theorem does not give us the existence of an analytic function $g$, it requires it.

Comment: @user412674 No, that's not correct. The idea is to prove the statement by contradiction. **If $f$ was analytic**, then $g$ would be analytic. By the identity theorem this would imply $g=0$, and so $f(z) = g(z)-2^{-1/z} = 2^{-1/z}$ would be analytic. As explained in my answer, $z \mapsto 2^{-1/z}$ is not continuous at $0$ (hence not analytic), and so we arrive at a contradiction. Consequently, there cannot exist an analatic function $f$ with the desired property.

Comment: That's just wrong: How you show that $g$ is also analytic? We have $g(1/n) =f(1/n)$, but the identity theorem requires that both functions are analytic on the whole unit disc. Thus, we cannot conclude that $f=g$ on the punctured unit disc. For example $h(z) = 2^{-1/z}(1+ \sin(2\pi/z))$ satisfies also $h(1/n) = 2^{-n}$, but $h \neq g$!

Comment: @p4sch There is nothing wrong about my answer itself (because I'm just saying that $2^{-1/z}$ is not continuous at $z=0$) but you are right that the reasoning via the identity theorem doesn't work that way... which I failed to realize. Sorry about that.