# Help in deciding the existense or non-existense of analytic function(complex analysis)

Tags: complex-analysis

How can I prove or disprove ?: Can there exist an analytic function $f(1/n)=(1/2)^n$[consider any suitable domain];$n\in N$ and $n\ge 2......(A)$
Now if I have to prove or disprove :$f(1/n)=(-1)^n/n $ exists or doesn't.I can first apply IVT to show there does exist a sequence of zeros of $f$.Then by, Idntity theorem(a.k.a. Uniqueness theorem),I can show that such $f$ is impossible to exist.
But in (A),I think there exists such function but don't have any idea how to prove it(or disprove it if my assumption is incorrect).
Please help me through this problem.I'll appreciate any help towards this.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Sorry but this is pretty badly stated. For example, where is $f$ defined and analytic?

Comment: @zhw.,$f(1/n)=(1/2)^n$ is given and the question is whether such an analytic $f$ exists or not?

Comment: An analytic $f$ defined where?

Comment: @zhw.,Conider any suitable domain.Can such an analytic function exist?

Comment: Well would a suitable domain be the open right half plane?

Comment: @zhw.,you just have to prove such an analytic function exists or doesn't whatever domain you take.Does there exists any such analytic $f$ satisfying the conditions stated in OP?

Comment: Related (possibly a duplicate, depending on your assumptions): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/392682

Comment: @mrf,my doubt didn't clear .

Comment: (1)By analytic, without any conditions, means analytic on the whole complex plane

Comment: @user254665,Please read OP.

Comment: For both, the existence is decided by whether $0$ belongs to the domain of the function or not.

Comment: @DanielFischer,suppose $0$ belongs to the domain of $f$,then I define $h(z)=f(z)-(1/2)^{1/z}$,I want to use identity theorem which can't be used for $z=0$ because $h$ is not entire.So how to proceed.

Comment: If $0$ is in the domain, $f$ has a Taylor expansion with centre $0$. Show that that isn't compatible with $f(1/n) = 2^{-n}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer,I found that $f^{(n)}=0$ for all $n$,that is $f(1/n)=0$ which is not compatible with $f(1/n)=2^{-n}$.Is it correct?

Comment: If your argument for $f^{(n)}(0) = 0$ for all $n$ is correct, that is correct.

Comment: @DanielFischer,I proved it like this by cauchy 's ML inequality:$f^{(m)}\le \left(\frac{M_R\fact m}{R^m}\right)$[where $M_R$ is max. value of $f(1/n)$ on $|z|=R$.Am I right?

Comment: From the single point $1/n$ on the circle, you have not enough information to use that. $M_R$ could be anything.

Comment: @DanielFischer,but I am assuming $f$ to be analytic.So $M_R $ will exist.

Comment: Sure, it will exist (for $R$ small enough that the circle $\lvert z\rvert = R$ is contained in the domain of $f$). But you don't know how large it will be, since you only know what would be $f(1/n)$ for positive integers $n$.